# How to create a K8s tls secret using pfx certificate stored in Azure key vault and Azure CLI

Tags: kubernetes, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

I am trying to create a k8s tls secret (data and key) using a pfx certificate that I would like to retrieve from Azure key vault using Azure CLI. It doesn't work because Azure downloads the public part(certificate) and the secret part(key) separately and then creating the k8s secret fails. Here's my script.

```
cert_key=cert.key
cert_pem=cert.pem
cert_pfx=cert.pfx
keyvault_name=akv_name
cert_name=akv_cert_name
secret_name=cert_pw_secret

#Get the password of the pfx certificate
secret_value=$(az keyvault secret show --name $secret_name --vault-name $keyvault_name  -o tsv --query value)

#Download the secret
az keyvault secret download --file $cert_key --name $cert_name --vault-name $keyvault_name

#Download the public part of the certificate
az keyvault certificate download --file $cert_pfx --name $cert_name --vault-name $keyvault_name

#Convert pfx to pem using openssl
#This will return an error:
#139728379422608:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1239:
#139728379422608:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:405:Type=PKCS12

openssl pkcs12 -in $cert_pfx  -clcerts -nokeys -out $cert_pem -password pass:$secret_value


#Convert pfx to key using openssl
#This will return an error:
#140546015532944:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1239:
#140546015532944:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:405:Type=PKCS12

openssl  pkcs12 -in $cert_pfx -nocerts -out $cert_key -password pass:$secret_value

#Create the k8s secret
kubectl create secret tls secret-ssl --cert=$cert_pem --key=$cert_key
```

Any idea why it's not working?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the issue in my environment and got the below results***

***I have created the RG & KV and secrets***

```
az keyvault create -n kv_name -g RG_name
az keyvault secret set --vault-name kv_name --name secret_name --value "value"
```

[image]

***I have added the polices to access the secrets***

***We can find the SPN id in active directory by creating with keyvault***

[image]

```
az keyvault set-policy -n <kv-name> --spn <spn-id> --secret-permissions get
```

[image]

***Added the certificate using below command***

```
az keyvault certificate create --vault-name <kv-name> --name <cert-name> -p "$(az keyvault certificate get-default-policy -o json)"
```

***I have added the polices to access the certificates***

```
az keyvault set-policy -n <kv-name> --spn <spn-id> --certificate-permissions get
```

***I have generated the private key using below command***

`openssl genrsa 2048 > private-key.key`

[image]

***Generated the certificate and i have converted the file into .pfx***

```
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha256 -days 365 -key private-key.key -out certificate.cert
```

[image]

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey private-key.key -in certificate.cert
```

[image]

***Encoded string and store it as a secret in Azure Key Vault. I have used the PowerShell commands to convert the `.pxf` file.***

```
$fileContentBytes = get-content ‘certificate.pfx' -AsByteStream
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fileContentBytes) | Out-File ‘pfx-encoded-bytes.pem
```

[image]

***The secret needs to have the content type set to "application/x-pkcs12" to tell Azure Key Vault that it is in PKCS file format.***

```
az keyvault secret set --vault-name <kv-name> --name <secret-name> --file pfx-encoded-bytes.pem --description "application/x-pkcs12"
```

[image]

***Downloaded the certificate using below command***

```
az keyvault certificate download --file certificate1.pem --name my-certificate --vault-name komali-test
```

***Converted the pfx to pem using openssl***

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out certificate.pem -password pass:123
```

[image]

***I have converted .pfx to key using openssl***

```
openssl  pkcs12 -in certtificate.pfx -nocerts -out private-key.key -password pass:XXXX
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me, I created another answer for the sake of completeness but I will accept yours. I just would like that you make few changes before accepting it. For example, you created a secret but you downloaded a certificate, I am not sure how this worked! Also, in your solution the base64 decoding is not mentioned, which would cause it to fail. And last, the default password when downloading from Azure KV is empty string. I wanted to mention it explicitly to make it clear to anyone, and also passing it with the command, this will help with automation.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply @mangawy, By sing this command $fileContentBytes = get-content ‘certificate.pfx' -AsByteStream  [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fileContentBytes) | Out-File ‘pfx-encoded-bytes.pfx’ will get the content as a byte stream and convert to base64 and stored as .pfx file and the default password while downloading is not empty i have mentioned the password and I hide it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That's correct, but when you we try to extract the key and pem files after download, it won't work if they are still base64 encoded, at least they didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @komali-annem's solution, I created another answer:
Assuming you have an existing pfx file in Azure keyvault.
Download the pfx file from Azure portal, let's name it cert_main.pfx
Then:

```
#-----First part (upload to Azure keyvault) -----

    kv_secret_name=kv-secret-name
    kv_name=kv-test
    cert_pfx=cert_main.pfx

    #Convert pfx to Base64 encoded   
    cert_pfx_encoded=$(cat $cert_pfx | openssl enc -base64)
    
    #Create a secret out of the encoded file
    az keyvault secret set --name $kv_secret_name --vault-name $kv_name --value "$cert_pfx_encoded" --description "application/x-pkcs12"

#-----Second part (Download and create TLS secret)-----

    kv_secret_name=kv-secret-name
    cert_key=cert.key
    cert_pem=cert.pem
    kv_name=kv-test
    k8s_secret_name=secret-ssl
    
    #Download the secret from KV ...
    az kv secret download --file b64_pfx.pem --name $kv_secret_name --vault-name $kv_name
    
    #Base64 decode...
    cat b64_pfx.pem | base64 -d > cert.pfx
    
    #Extract pem from pfx using openssl
    openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out $cert_pem -passin pass:""
    
    #Extract pem from pfx using openssl
    openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -nocerts -out $cert_key -passin pass:"" -passout pass:"1234"
    
    #Create password-less key
    openssl rsa -in $cert_key -out $cert_key -passin pass:"1234"
    
    #Create the k8s secret
    kubectl create secret tls $k8s_secret_name --cert=cert.pem --key=cert.key --namespace monitoring
    
    #Remove intermediate files
    rm $cert_pem $cert_key b64_pfx.pem cert.pfx
```